# ¿Como cambiar el orden en que se imprime en un programa con MultiHilos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

Programa paralelizado, que utiliza `n` hilos independientes para procesar una lista dada de `m` solicitudes. Los hilos toman las solicitudes en el orden en que se dan en la entrada. Si hay un hilo libre, éste toma inmediatamente la siguiente solicitud de la lista. Sin embargo, si un hilo ya ha comenzado a procesar una solicitud, no se puede interrumpir o detener hasta la termine de procesar. Si varios hilos intentan tomar solicitudes de la lista simultáneamente, el hilo con un índice menor será el que la atienda. Para cada solicitud se sabe el tiempo exacto que cualquier hilo tardará en procesarla.

Determine el hilo que procesa cada una de las solicitudes, y el tiempo en que empezará a hacerlo. Asuma que el tiempo inicial es 0.

**Entrada:**

La primera línea es un número `T` que representa la cantidad de casos de prueba. A continuación sigue la descripción de cada caso.

La primera línea de cada caso contiene 2 números, `n` y `m`, que representan el número de hilos y el número de solicitudes, respectivamente. Luego sigue una línea con `m` números, donde el i-ésimo número denota el tiempo que toma procesar la solicitud `i` (por cualquier hilo).

**Salida:**

Por cada caso, imprima `m` líneas. Cada línea debe tener dos números separados por un espacio: el hilo que procesa la i-ésima solicitud y el tiempo en que la comienza a procesar.

Este es mi código:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time
print_lock=threading.Lock()

def job(request,thread):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with print_lock:
        print(thread,request)

def worker(count):
    """Funtion that executes the thread"""
    timeOfExecution=0
    while True:
        request=queue.get()
        job(timeOfExecution,count)
        timeOfExecution+=request
        queue.task_done()


T = int(input())

for case in range(T):
    N, M = map(int, input().split(' '))
    if 1<=N and N<=100000 and 1<=M and M<=100000:
        requests= list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
        queue=Queue()
        for i in requests:
            queue.put(i)
        for i in range(N):
            t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
            t.daemon=True
            t.start()
        queue.join()
```

Para el caso de prueba:

> 1
>      4 20
>      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Obtengo:

> 1 0
>      2 0
>      0 0
>      3 0
>      0 1
>      1 1
>      2 1
>      3 1
>      1 2
>      2 2
>      0 2
>      3 2
>      2 3
>      0 3
>      1 3
>      3 3
>      0 4
>      1 4
>      2 4
>      3 4

Pero lo que me deberia salir es esto:

> 0 0
>   1 0
>   2 0
>   3 0
>   0 1
>   1 1
>   2 1
>   3 1
>   0 2
>   1 2
>   2 2
>   3 2
>   0 3
>   1 3
>   2 3
>   3 3
>   0 4
>   1 4
>   2 4
>   3 4

El resultado es el correcto pero lo imprime en un orden diferente. ¿Alguien sabe por que ocurre esto?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Este es StackOverflow en Español, por tanto las preguntas aqui escritas, deben ser formuladas en esa lengua